# FileSavePicker task not showing in Window.Storage.Pickers in wp8 c#

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8, filesavepicker

I'm trying to save a video file using FilePicker Task but its not showing FileSavePicker task in Solution. Below a screen shot is attached

There are only 4 tasks showing in Windows.Storage.Pickers

1. FileExtensionVector
2. FileOpenPicker
3. PickerLocationId
4. PickerViewMode

Here is code I'm using

```
        async void TrimVideoFile()
    {
        Windows.Storage.StorageFile source;
        Windows.Storage.StorageFile destination;

        var openPicker = new Windows.Storage.Pickers.FileOpenPicker();

        openPicker.SuggestedStartLocation = Windows.Storage.Pickers.PickerLocationId.VideosLibrary;
        openPicker.FileTypeFilter.Add(".wmv");
        openPicker.FileTypeFilter.Add(".mp4");

        source = await openPicker.PickSingleFileAsync();

        var savePicker = new Windows.Storage.Pickers.FileSavePicker()
        savePicker.SuggestedStartLocation =
            Windows.Storage.Pickers.PickerLocationId.VideosLibrary;

        savePicker.DefaultFileExtension = ".mp4";
        savePicker.SuggestedFileName = "New Video";

        savePicker.FileTypeChoices.Add("MPEG4", new string[] { ".mp4" });

        destination = await savePicker.PickSaveFileAsync();

        // Method to perform the transcoding.
        TrimFile(source, destination);
    }
```

Its showing only 4 tasks. What to do to use FileSavePicker task. I'm using Visual Studio 2012 and my targeted app is Windows Phone 8.0 App.

Answer (score 1):

File pickers are not available on Windows Phone 8. They were added with Windows Phone 8.1.

See the Version section in the [FileSavePicker docs](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/windows.storage.pickers.filesavepicker.aspx) on MSDN:

> **Minimum supported phone**  Windows Phone 8.1 [Windows Phone Silverlight 8.1 and Windows Runtime apps]

Comment: Is there any alternative to FileSavePicker in WindowPhone8?

Comment: No. They are a new feature for 8.1. You can write your own picking UI, but it  can only target locations the app can read already.